# significance of using c:out tag

Tags: java, jsp

I have two jsp files written as below

index.jsp

```
<form action="process.jsp" method="post">
FirstName:<input type="text" name="fname"/><br/>
LastName:<input type="text" name="lname"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

process.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

First Name:<c:out value="${param.fname}"></c:out><br/>
Last Name:<c:out value="${param.lname}"></c:out>
</br>
First Name:${param.fname}
</br>
Last Name:${param.lname}
```

when we give some input I get I get the same output:

```
First Name:nm
Last Name:nm 
First Name:nm 
Last Name:nm
```

so I am little bit confuse that what is the significance of using c:out tag??
if we can do the same work without c:out then why we have this tag available in JSP. I am new to EL that's why asking silly question..

Comment: try assigning value `<script>alert('1');</script>` to `param.fname` and try both approaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[c:out tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) not only prints the characters but also escapes HTML characters.Thus prevents possible  **cross-site scripting attacks.** [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

if param.fname is set to something like below:

```
 param.fname = <script>while (true) alert("possible cross scripting attack");</script>
```

This script will be executed in the  case of `${param.fname}`. But it will not be executed in case of c:out tag.